# How is the set of condensation points of an uncountable subset of $\Bbb{R}^k$ perfect?

Tags: general-topology

My textbook defines a perfect set $E$ to be a closed set such that every point in $E$ is a limit point of $E$.

It also asks me to prove the following:

> Suppose $E\subset \Bbb{R^k}$, E is uncountable, and let $P$ be the set of all condensation points of $E$. Prove that $P$ is perfect.

I wonder why that is. If $E=(0,1)\subset\Bbb{R^1}$, then $P=\{0,1\}$. How is $P$ perfect? It is closed, but neither $1$ nor $0$ are limit points of the set.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240593/how-to-prove-that-the-set-of-condensation-points-of-an-uncountable-subset-of-the) for an almost-duplicate question.

Comment: Finite sets have no limit points. So $A=\{1\}$ is a set where $1\in A$ but 1 is not a limit point of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The set of condensation points of $E = (0,1)$ is not $\{0,1\}$, but the entire closed interval $[0,1]$.  $x$ is a "condensation point" if every open ball around $x$ contains uncountably many points in $E$--this can be the case whether or not $x$ itself is a member of $E$.

Re edit: $\{1\}$ is not a perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^1$.  $1$ is not a limit point of $\{1\}$, so the set is not perfect.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for your help.